# How can we show this identity for the material derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, optimization, numerical-optimization, fluid-dynamics, diffeomorphism

Let $T(\;\cdot\;,t)$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism on $\mathbb R^d$ for $t\in[0,\tau]$ with $T(\;\cdot\;,0)=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^d}$, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ and $\Omega_t:=T(\Omega,t)$ and $\Gamma_t:=\partial\Omega_t$ for $t\in[0,\tau]$. How do we obtain the last displayed equation in the following excerpt taken from a [paper](https://d-nb.info/1031513809/34#page=33) (see p. 19)?

[image]

I don't get how they've obtained this from the assumption that $z_t:\Omega_t\to\mathbb R$ has a $C^1$-extension to a neighborhood of $\overline\Omega_t$ for all $t$. Since $z=z_0$, $\nabla z$ is the gradient of $z_0$. Wouldn't we need something like $z_t=\left.g\right|_{\Omega_t}$ for all small enough $t$ and some $g\in C^1(O)$, where $O$ is an open subset containing all $\Omega_t$?

Comment: Isn't that what a regular extension into a neighborhood of $\bar \Omega_t$ means?  Also, best not to use the symbol $f$, when it is used elsewhere in the text.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith To me it means that for all $t$, there is an open subset $O_t$ with $O_t\supseteq\overline\Omega_t$ and a function $g_t\in C^1(O_t)$ with $\left.g_t\right|_{\Omega_t}=z_t$. How do you understand it?

Comment: So isn't your question something like this?  "I don't understand how they have obtained this from assumption X.  Wouldn't they need assumption X?"

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith I'm sorry, but I don't understand your comment. I understand their assumption in the way that I've described in my last comment and I don't get why this yields the claim they make. Please take note of the related question I've asked for this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3817399/47771.

Comment: OK, I understand your question now.  You were describing assumption X, but you didn't see why it was needed.

Answer (score 1):

When the paper writes
$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{z_t(x) - z(x)}t + \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{z_t(T(x,t)) - z_t(x)} t$$
we need to know that $z_t(x)$ exists.  But we only know that $x \in \Omega_0$, not that it exists in $\Omega_t$.  But if we know $z$ has a $C^1$ extension to a neighborhood of $\bar\Omega_0$, then we can say that for $0 \leq t \leq t_0$ we have $z(x)$ is defined for $x \in \Omega_t$.  Note that the choice of $t_0$ can depend upon $z$, so the negative answer to this question [If $T_t$ is a diffeomorphism with $T_0=\text{id}$ and $O$ is a neighborhood of $\Omega$, then $T_t(\Omega)\subseteq O$ for small $t$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3816969/if-t-t-is-a-diffeomorphism-with-t-0-textid-and-o-is-a-neighborhood-of/3816975#3816975) doesn't apply.

Comment: (a) What do you mean by "$z\in\Omega_0$"? Do you mean $z([0,t_0])\subseteq\Omega_0$? (Note that they've defined $z(x)=z_0(x_0)=z_0(x)$.)

Comment: (b) why can we infer from $z=z_0$ having a $C^1$-extension to a neighborhood of $\overline\Omega_0$ that $z_t$ is defined on $x\in\Omega_0$? (c) And lastly, my main problem is: Don't we need some kind of differentiability assumption in time as well? Something like I've assumed in [the other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3817399/47771)? (Note that $Y$ in that question is differentiable in both arguments.)

Comment: (a) That was a typo which I fixed.  (b) is now moot.  (c) - that is a good point.  You need that the extension is $C^1$ in both the $x$ and the $t$ variable.

Comment: (a) I think there's still a typo. You now wrote "We have $z(x)$ for $x\in\Omega_t$". I guess there's something missing? (c) In order for the gradient $\nabla z$ to be well-defined, $\Omega$ needs to be open. Can we generalize the result in the case where $\Omega$ is only an arbitrary submanifold by replacing $\nabla z$ with the pushforward?

Comment: I fixed the typo.  $\nabla z$ is only defined if there is an extension beyond the boundary of $\Omega_0$.  But the hypothesis gives us that.

Comment: Merely knowing that $z_0$ has a $C^1$-extension $Z$ at $x$ is *not* enough to obtain a well-defined differential of $z_0$ at $x$, since ${\rm D}Z(x)$ will depend on the choice of $Z$ (i.e. is not uniquely determined by $z_0$). If $\Omega$ is open, then ${\rm D}Z(x)$ is uniquely determined, since then $z_0$ and $Z$ coincide (by assumption) on an open set. Otherwise, assuming that $\Omega$ is only a submanifold, we need to consider the pushforward $T_x(z_0)v_0(x)$ of $v_0(x):=\left.\frac\partial{\partial t}T_t(x)\right|_{t=0}$ by $z_0$ at $x$ instead.

Comment: BTW, we also need to show that $\frac{\partial W}{\partial t}(0,x)$ does not depend on the choice of the extension $W:[0,\delta)\times O\to\mathbb R$, where $O$ is an open neighborhood of $\{T_t(x):t\in[0,\delta)\}$ and $W(t,T_t(x))=z_t(T_t(x))$ for all $t\in[0,\delta)$.

Comment: Still be interested in this. What do you think about my last two comments?

Comment: I do wonder if we are getting caught in the weeds.  In the rest of the thesis you are reading, does he consider time varying domains a lot?  And if so, would it make sense to simply use $\dot z$ as the definition of the material derivative, and think of $\frac \partial{\partial t} - u \cdot \nabla$ as a conveninet code for the material derivative?

Comment: My main focus is not on this specific thesis. I just cited one of the various references which make the desired claim without proving it rigorously.

Comment: BTW, note that I've missed to add the assumption $T(\;\cdot\;,0)=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^d}$. Does that help?