# Smooth extension and derivative with respect to $t$ of a function $y_t$ on a variable domain $\Omega_t$

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, differential-topology, frechet-derivative, diffeomorphism

Let $\tau>0$, $d\in\mathbb N$, $T_t$ be a $C^1$-diffeomorphism on $\mathbb R^d$ for $t\in[0,\tau)$ with $T_0=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^d}$, $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ and $y_t:\Omega_t:=T_t(\Omega)\to\mathbb R$ for $t\in[0,\tau)$.

Assume there is an open neighborhood $O$ of $\bigcup_{t\in[0,\:\tau)}\Omega_t$ and a Fréchet differentiable $Y:[0,\tau)\times O\to\mathbb R$ with $$\left.Y(t,\;\cdot\;)\right|_{\Omega_t}=y_t\;\;\;\text{for all }t\in[0,\tau).$$

> Are we able to show that $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial t}(0,x)$ does not depend on the choice of $(\tau,O,Y)$ for all $x\in\Omega$?

Comment: The domain of $Y$ is $[0,\tau)\times O$, but you want to look at the behavior of $Y$ in a neighborhood of $(0,x)$ for some $x\in\Omega$. This only makes sense if $x\in O$, which doesn't seem to necessarily be the case.

Comment: @Thorgott I'm sorry, I've missed to add the assumption that $T_0=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb R^d}$. Note that then $x\in\Omega=\Omega_0\subseteq O$. (What are you denoting by $(0,x)$? $x$ is a vector.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\tau=\infty$, $d=1$, $T_0=\operatorname{id}_{\mathbb{R}}$, $T_t\colon\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\,x\mapsto x+1$ for $t>0$, $\Omega=\{0\}\subset\mathbb{R}$, $\Omega_t:=T_t(\Omega)$ (i.e. $\Omega_0=\{0\}$ and $\Omega_t=\{1\}$ for $t>0$) and $y_t\colon\Omega_t\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\,x\mapsto0$. Then $\bigcup_{t\in[0,\infty)}\Omega_t=\{0,1\}$, so $O:=\mathbb{R}$ is an open neighborhood. The condition on $Y\colon[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ simply becomes $Y(0,0)=0$ and $Y(t,1)=0$ for $t>0$. This is satisfied by both $Y\colon[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\,(t,x)\mapsto0$ and $Y^{\prime}\colon[0,\infty)\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R},\,(t,x)\mapsto(1-x)t$, both of which are differentiable (polynomial even), yet $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial t}(0,0)=0$ and $\frac{\partial Y^{\prime}}{\partial t}(0,0)=1$. So the choice does matter.

Most of the choices in this counter-example were arbitrary and a myriad others are probably possible. The one thing that makes this possible is choosing the diffeomorphisms so that $\Omega_0$ and $\Omega_t,\,t>0$ are separated. Knowing $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial t}(0,x),\,x\in\Omega_0$ requires knowing $Y(t,x)$ for $t$ in some neighborhood of $0$. We do know $Y(0,x)=y_0(x)$ by hypothesis, but we only know $Y(t,x)$ for $t>0$ directly if $x\in\Omega_t$, so making $\Omega_0$ and $\Omega_t,\,t>0$ disjoint removes this possibility. Making them separated just gives us enough space to freely interpolate between them, at which point there ought to be enough freedom for the partials to be just about anything.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This drives me nuts. $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial t}(0,x)$ does depend on the choice of $(\tau,O,Y)$, how is $z'(x)$ in [this question/paper](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3817029/47771) well-defined then? (Note that $z'(x)$ there is equal to $\frac{\partial Z}{\partial t}(0,x)$ for some extension $Z$ of the same kind as $Y$ described here.)

Comment: I don't know about that.

Comment: Wait a second, as you wrote, the main ingredient of your counterexample is the separating of $\Omega_0$ from $\Omega_t$ for $t>0$. This should actually never happen in practice. First of all, we usually assume that $(t,x)\mapsto T_t(x)$ is jointly continuous (this is trivially the case in your example). But more crucially, $\Omega$ is usually a $d$-dimensional properly embedded $C^1$-submanifold. Do you think this helps to show the desired claim?

Comment: Moreover, it can be assumed that $$T_t(x)=x+\int_0^tv(s,T_s(x))\:{\rm d}s$$ for some suitable $v$.

Comment: No, my $T$ is not jointly continuous. I do not understand your point about $\Omega$, a $d$-dimensional submanifold of a $d$-dimensional manifold is the same as a non-empty open subset of that manifold and as such never properly embedded unless it is the whole manifold itself (in which case the question is trivial). You can put $T(t,x)=x+t$ in my example, which is jointly continuous and has your desired form with $v\equiv1$. You still won't get any uniqueness.

Comment: I've meant "submanifold with boundary".

Comment: Then put $\Omega=[0,1]$. It's probably awkward to write down, but it's visually obvious that you still won't get uniqueness.